# group algebra $kS_2$ isomorphic to direct product of matrix algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebras

if we let $k=\mathbb{C}$, I need to show that the group algebra $kS_2$ isomorphic to direct product of matrix algebras. Another question is if it is true for an arbitrary field $k$. If we let $S_2=\{e,s\}$ I was told to look at $b_1=(e+s)/2,b_2=(e-s)/2$.

An element $x\in\mathbb{C}S_2$ looks like $x=c_1e+c_2s,c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{C}$ or equivalently, a function with value $c_1,c_2$ at $e,s$ respectively. I also know that $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to the group algebra generated by $\begin{pmatrix}x &y\\-y&x\end{pmatrix},x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. I failed to find a product of matrix algebras that is suitable here. I need tips but I don't want a solution straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

By Maschke's theorem, the algebra group $\;\Bbb CG\;$ , for *any* finite group $\;G\;$ , is semisimple.

Now just apply [Artin-Wedderburn's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem)

Comment: Beat me by some seconds. `;-)`

Comment: Hehe @egreg. One of my professors was Shimshon Amitsur, so go figure if I can allow myself to forget these huge theorems...:)

Comment: Well, I had to look for the name of Maschke, because I didn't remember it (but I remembered the theorem).

Comment: Welp, I think I was blind, given we just learned about Masche's theorem, so this should have been obvious. This also answers the question about arbitrary fields $k$: it holds if the characteristic of the field is not 2.